# Could I please get my question deleted

Tags: support, delete

I would like my question to be deleted. I made a mistake in posting it, it is at 
[Cool text based adventure game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237126/cool-text-based-adventure-game)

Answer (score 6):

You indicated the real problem is you posted something that in hindsight you shouldn't have shared, because your classmates ran with your solution to a homework problem. That's unfortunate.

Normally, [we don't like removing answered questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/631/52915). However, exceptions can be made whenever legal problems come up. A wise member of our community got asked about the following situation during a [moderator election](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8719/52915):

> 6. A question is flagged: ***Please delete this question - my boss has seen it and says it contains confidential code - he's freaking out and wants me to remove it, but I can't delete it***. The question was asked 3 days before, it has 2 answers, one is accepted. How do you respond?
>
> Heh, that's my question. The answer is to refer the flagger to the DMCA takedown process for Stack Exchange. It is unfair for existing answers to be penalized by deletion. The DMCA takedown process takes the judgement responsibility out of the hands of the Code Review mod and puts it in the Stack Exchange staff's process. This is a legal issue, and should be dealt with by the people responsible for those activities. Note that a mod cannot fully delete a question (deleted posts can still be viewed by folk with high rep), so the SE staff are the only people who can fully purge the post.

That's the policy. The long story is written down [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/269301) and boils down to "moderators won't remove your question".

A possible solution is for your post(s) (both this meta post and the actual question on the main site if you want) to be [disassociated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/269301) from your account. The posts will be awarded to anonymous users and no longer be linked towards your account. We'll clean up the comments and that's mostly it.

So, unless there's a legal problem here, in which case you'd have to [Contact](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) the team that's *above* the moderators and which are actual employees of Stack Exchange/Overflow, the posts won't be removed.

Comment: I'd also give this recommendation: If your classmates are ripping off your code, it's not your problem - it's theirs. Report it to your teacher/professor. If, however, the truth would be that it's actually *you* that copied someone else's code and got into problems for that, then I hope you have learned your lesson.

Comment: For your information, I was falsely accused of sending my work to another student, not the other way round. Both of us got in trouble although the other student was the one to blame.